# Any Python api document websites with instant search like ruby-docs.com and jqapi.com?

Tags: python, documentation

Real-time api browser websites like ruby-docs.com and jqapi.com are very useful, it there any  similar website for Python?

Updated:

By real-time I means instant search. docs.python.org is well-wriiten but a little hard for searching (comparing with ruby-docs.com and jqapi.co).

Comment: you mean like docs.python.org ?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you mean by real-time API in this respect, a Python API?.

The documentatation at http://docs.python.org is very useful and complete, supports multiple version of the Python language (starting with 2.6) and has search.

The search there is not as interactive e.g. the one on ruby-docs.com.

I use docs.python.org quite often and personally do not miss that interactivity, as my IDE for Python has a better interactive information than a website can provide.